# How to print a Line for Receipt in Epson Printer with feed

Tags: java, android, printing, thermal-printer, epson

I want to print a Line for Receipt in Epson Printer with feed.
For eg. I have a receipt where it has `SNo, Item Name, Category, Cost.`

So, I want to print them with some space(`feed`).

Currently I got some `code` to print simple line is as follows:

```
StringBuilder textData = new StringBuilder();
 textData.append("4 3 CUP BLK TEAPOT    9.99 R\n");
```

And `append` is being referred From `Jar` file `StringBuilder.java`

```
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

from above code I am getting output of line `4 3 CUP BLK TEAPOT    9.99` in receipt.

I want to Print a line using code using feed in between words (`SNo, Item Name, Category, Cost.`) in printing receipt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Epson epos sdk receipt alignment issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217629/epson-epos-sdk-receipt-alignment-issue)

Answer (score 0):

This below code will help you to print a line and modify according to you need-

```
StringBuilder textData7 = new StringBuilder();
textData7.append("Hello there, How are you doing");
mPrinter.addText(textData7.toString());
```

To Print use `mPrinter` and dont forget to add `Jar` files before `configuring` app

And to `Feed` line use below code:

```
method = "addFeedLine";
mPrinter.addFeedLine(1);
```

`addFeedLine` will help you `feed` number of line you want to feed. Increase number 1 it will give you multiple lines feed.

Use `Hex Code` for `spacing` and `2tabs-3tabs-4tabs` for receipt printing.
[Click here to get the Epson printer Codes.](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/epson_printer_codes.html)

Hope this helps, else you can ask in comment.