# Sample code for xamarin android receipt printing using Epson SDK

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, thermal-printer

[image: Solution Explorer]

I am totally new to the xamarin world and I am current using Xamarin android framework to build an app which providing the feature of receipt printing on BLE/POS printer.

I am using Epson SDK ,these jar files converted into dl file  and it is added to my xamarin android project references

However, I am still confused and have no idea about how to print.
Could anyone help me or provide me some directions, or there are alternatives for my to achieve what I want,please help me i am in project dead line.
Thank you!

Comment: You should never ever post your code as a scrennshot. Code is simple text and SO has some very good highlighters for code buitlin.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be in C#, but these articles may be helpful. [Printing to POS Printers in Xamarin Forms Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62307091/9014308), [Epson ePOS SDK for Android (Xamarin) missing constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52166161/9014308), [Epson epos sdk receipt alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40217629/9014308)